# Resources consumed using a timer for interface monitoring instead of built in control events

Tags: .net

I' m wondering if using a timer to check if a container control has focus, instead of overriding a couple of methods that handle mouse and keyboard events, would save resources or consume even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. Let us consider t to be the period elapsed between focus checking. If during that period there is a lot of focus shifting, then clearly, the timer consumes less resources. If in that period nothing happens, then the timer consumes more resources.

Also, an event is self-aware, that is you know that clicking an element will make it focused, while the timer needs to check for all form elements.

EDIT:

To clarify, if someone uses a timer to do the job of event-handling instead of .net, then it is a periodic check protocol, which makes the event-handling lose its instant nature. This huge sacrifice is rewarded in some very specific cases, for instance, when events should logically cancel each-other, their handlers use a lot of resources and a given time span of wait for an event to be handled is not a huge waste in UX terms, however, in general, it is a bad design.

.net, on low-level does not periodically check whether an event occurred. That would imply an event queue somewhere, filling up with events and that would imply direct interaction with hardware across all the drivers. This is not the job of Frameworks. This is the job of the Operating System. However, a practical standard for Operating Systems is to use interrupt driven I/O. This protocol is all about interrupts. I guess by its name you already start to understand the idea, but I will describe how an event handling occurs:

- something happened (a key was used, a mouse button was clicked, a sensor registered motion, etc.)
- the hardware sends an interrupt signal to the computer
- the OS receives that signal and "understands" the nature of the interrupt
- the OS saves the state of the program where the event occurred
- the OS reads the INPR (input port) into memory/register and resets FGI (input flag) to allow further inputs

That last operation is the job of the Interrupt Service Routine, which, as we have seen above, does not periodically check whether there were hardware events, but is interrupted by them. .net uses an Interrupt Service Routine, therefore, when you register event handlers, they will not periodically check for the event to see whether it actually occurred, but are triggered by the Framework, since they are logically linked to the interrupts.

Comment: How the .net framework checks if something happened?

Comment: @anefeletos, more specifically?

Comment: I assume that the core function of .net or windows might rely on some periodically check for keyboard or mouse buttons activity.